# Cannot update my raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, update, apt

I try an update on my new raspberry pi 3.
I did sudo apt-get update and I've got "0% mirrordirector.raspbian.org"
Internet is ok but when I ping mirrordirector I've got 13 packets transmitted but 0 received and they are all lost...

Is it a server issue ? Can someone help me ?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Try again later if it is a server issue (possibly so), try to ping from another system to see if it is something with your Pi.

Comment: Thank you. I can ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org now but I can't on archive.raspberry.org on both pc. I will wait

Answer (score 0):

It was a DNS issue. I edit /etc/hosts and it works

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include some detail as to what you actually did.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.